# Running Two Singles Parallel and Handling the Scenarios

Tags: java, android, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I have two Singles (getChannels and getEPGs), both running in parallel. In most cases, getChannels is completed before getEPGs and I can connect the EPG's to the channels. However, I would like to handle the cases where getEPGs are completed before the getChannels.

In other words,

1. Both Singles are running parallel.
2. To connect the EPG, the channels must have been loaded.
3. If the getEPGs is completed before the getChannels, it must wait for the getChannels, and only then a method will be invoked
4. If the getEPGs fails, the app flow will continue regardless.

How can I accomplish this without relying on callbacks and while loops? I guess that there should be a reactive way to handle this case. Thanks in advance.

```
@GET
Single<ResponseBody> getChannels(@Url String url);

@Streaming
@GET
Single<ResponseBody> getEPGs(@Url String url);


getChannels [.............................]

getEPGs     [..........................................]
```

Answer (score 0):

Define your functions into a repository and access them through a viewModel.

```
public class Repository {
    @GET
    return Single<ResponseBody> getChannels(@Url String url);

    @Streaming
    @GET
    return Single<ResponseBody> getEPGs(@Url String url);
}
```

Now ViewModel class.

```
public class SiteListViewModel extends BaseViewModel {

private CompositeDisposable mDisposable;
private Repository mRepository;

  public void getData() {
      mDisposable.add(
          mRepository.getChannels().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(obj -> {"CALL SECOND FUNCTION OVER HERE"

                },throwable -> Log.e("Error", e.printStackTrace()))
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*2. To connect the EPG, the channels must have been loaded.*

Okay,

> ResponseBody channels = getChannels.blockingGet();

*3. If the getEPGs is completed before the getChannels, it must wait for the getChannels, and only then a method will be invoked*

Okay, wait for channels and call a method:

> ResponseBody channels = getChannels.blockingGet();
>
> aMethod(channels);

*4. If the getEPGs fails, the app flow will continue regardless.*

the above statements indeed ignores the result of `getEPGs()`.

So strictly speacing, all your conditions can be expressed simply: wait for `getChannels()` and ignore `getEPGs()`. That conditions are fully satisfied by the proposed 2 lines of code.